# Is a servlet created for every client in JSP/Tomcat?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web-applications

I´m creating my first java servlets but there is still a concept about the application server I don´t fully understand. If a .jsp file contains something like

```
<form id="login" action="Servlet" method="post">
```

then a *Servlet* instance is created for every client that visits the page or only once an it must handle concurrency and multiple requests by itself?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presence of a `form` tag doesnt have any relation to the `servlet`, when you deploy the application in a server, its always one instance per servlet. For every request to the `application`, the same `servlet` instance is used.
Its really important you code your `servlet` in a `thread-safe` manner